# How to use awk to compare six files for common elements

Tags: awk

To compare two fields of two files for common elements and print the common elements, I use this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$2 in a{print $2}' file1 file2
```

This compares column 2 of the two files.

Now, I have six of such files. How can I use awk to compare the column 2 of these six files for common elements, and print out the common elements?  Each file has only two fields.

My expectation is an output of only the common elements.

Thank you.

Comment: when common is more than one or common is all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values in column 2 of each file are unique within the file, then this is sufficient:

```
awk '{a[$2]++;} END {for (i in a) if (a[i] > 1) print i;}' \
    file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6
```

(assuming you want 'appears in more than one file'; change `> 1` to `== 6` if you want 'appears in all files').

If the values in column 2 could be repeated with a given file, then you have to work a bit harder, possibly like this:

```
awk '{ if (f[$2] != FILENAME) a[$2]++; f[$2] = FILENAME; }
     END { for (i in a) if (a[i] > 1) print i; }' \
     file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6
```

The array `f` keeps a record of which file last identified the value in `$2`; if that isn't the current file, then increment the count in array `a` and record that the current file identified the value in `$2`.  As before, tweak the condition in the `for` loop to adjust what gets printed.